# SpringSource integration with eclipse

Tags: java, sonarqube, springsource

I am attempting to integrate the sonarqube plug-in with eclipse. However, I want to do this on another machine that does not have network access. I have copied the .jar files into the Spring plugins folder. This does not properly install it.

I was wondering how I can go about this installation process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Doing a copy of plugins JAR is not a good idea. You will miss some items (especially features, config, ...).
You could download the update site content from http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/ and then copy it to your offline computer and configure a local update site (file://xxxx).